# How do you connect to a DataBase from a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Connection string file in `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="test1" connectionString = "Data Source=
              (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
              (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test1)));User Id=test1;Password=test1;" />

    <add name ="test2" connectionString = "Data Source=
              (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
              (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test1)));User Id=test2;Password=test2;" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

File in `Form` loading:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test1"].ConnectionString;
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString);
    OracleCommandBuilder cmdbld;
    OracleDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load Data
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da = new OracleDataAdapter("sql command", con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            cmdbld = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

So, how do I use a `ComboBox` to change connection between `test1` and `test2` here?
Right now, I only replace `test1` to `test2` but putting `comboBox1.Text` in `connectionStrings[]` doesn't work. What can I do here?

I can make another log in form and make one form for test1 and the other for `test2` connection but it seems very inefficient way to switch between server.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the code, that creates the connection down into the click eventhandler, then you can use comboBox1.Text in the connectionstring.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Load Data
   try
   {
      string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[comboBox1.Text].ConnectionString;
      OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString);
      con.Open();
      da = new OracleDataAdapter("sql command", con);
      ds = new DataSet();
      cmdbld = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
      da.Fill(ds);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
       con.Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works when you manually put `test1` or `test2` in as the index for `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[]` then your problem is with what is being returned from your comboBox1.

You don't show us that code, so we can't tell you exactly what is wrong, but try something like this:

```
var desiredServer = comboBox1.Text;
static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[desiredServer].ConnectionString;
```

and put a breakpoint on the second line to see exactly what you are really putting in there. If this does not solve your problem, then post your combobox and let us try again with better information.